# Unable to update table inside of while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying table in a while loop and has a button to update data for each row when clicked. But the update isn't happening .

The table column "Enroll" is to be updated based on clicking the submit button for that row.

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
mysql_select_db('mydata');

$query = "SELECT * FROM internship";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
    if($row['Enroll']=="unenroll")
    { 
        echo '<div class="intern">';
        echo '<h1>'.$row['course'] . "</h1>" ;
        echo '<h2>'.$row['compay'] . "</h2>";
        echo "<h3>Stipend:Rs." . $row['stipend'] ."<h3>";
        echo "<h3>Duration:".$row['duration']."month</h3>";
        echo "<h3>Start-date:".$row['start date']."</h3>";
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<form method="post" action="">';
        echo '<button name="add_to_cart" type="submit" ><h2>Enroll</h2></button>';
        echo '</form>';
        if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
        {
            $selectedProduct =  $row["ID"];
            $sql='UPDATE internship SET Enroll="enrolled" WHERE ID="$selectedProduct"';
            mysql_query($connection,$sql);    
            header("location:enrolled.php");            
         }
     }
}
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

I am not able to update. Please help.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: they are working fine for me as i am using xampp server

Comment: Your update is happening for the __first__ record with `unenroll` status in a table.

Comment: even the first record is not getting updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

1. You haven't included any *ID* value in the button of each row.

   ```
   echo '<button name="add_to_cart" type="submit" ><h2>Enroll</h2></button>';
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --> no value="..."
   ```
2. You are not using the selected row i.e. the row for which the button has been clicked to update the table row with *enrolled*.

   ```
   $selectedProduct =  $row["ID"];
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

So your code should be like this:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
    mysql_select_db('mydata');

    if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])){
        $selectedProduct = $_POST['add_to_cart'];
        $sql ="UPDATE internship SET Enroll = 'enrolled' WHERE ID = '$selectedProduct'";
        mysql_query($connection,$sql);    
        header("location:enrolled.php");   
        exit();
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM internship";
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
        if($row['Enroll']=="unenroll"){ 
            ?>
            <div class="intern">
                <h1><?php echo $row['course']; ?></h1>
                <h2><?php echo $row['compay']; ?></h2>
                <h3>Stipend:Rs <?php echo $row['stipend']; ?><h3>
                <h3>Duration: <?php echo $row['duration']; ?> month</h3>
                <h3>Start-date: <?php echo $row['start date']; ?></h3>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <button name="add_to_cart" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" type="submit"><h2>Enroll</h2></button>
            </form>
            <?php
        }
    }

    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: I suppose there's no need to generate table if POST is set. Because `header` will redirect immediately.

Comment: Not sure why you put curly braces around the variable being interpolated. That doesn't do anything in this case.

Comment: @u_mulder Yes, I missed that part, moved `if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])){...}` at the top of the page.

Comment: @tadman Cannot recall but somewhere I had read some benefit of using curly braces to enclose variable in SQL statements. Never mind, removed `'`s from the SQL statement.

Comment: Variables *do not belong* in SQL statements and giving them little wings for protection seems more like superstition than anything useful. In regular PHP string interpolation they are required for *complex interpolations*, where `"You're {$person->age} years old!"` is a valid use.

Comment: actually i am querying an internship portfolio with a button to enroll into the internship and on submitting it should update from unenroll to enrolled and then view it in the enrolled.php page.The ID is the column of the table not the id element

Comment: @ShauryaNigam The proposed solution does what you said above^. After getting redirected to *enrolled.php* page, just query the table and display the results. What is not working for you now?

Comment: The updation should happen for the selected row but the updation is not happening at all.

Comment: @ShauryaNigam I missed to use `<button>..</button>` in the form, updated my answer. Please check again. In case it's not working again, please paste the output of `var_dump($_POST['add_to_cart']);` in [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) and give it's link here. By the way, write `var_dump($_POST['add_to_cart']);` at the top of your page and capture it's output after you hit the *Enroll* button.